# How to install Provisioning Certificate on the device for OTA (wireless) App distribution with Enterprise iOS account

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning, enterprise-distribution

I have setup OTA (Over-the-Air) Enterprise distribution for my iOS App through my enterprise iOS account. It's all setup except the only problem is that it gives an `unable to download error`. Most probable reason that I see here that the device on which I try to install doesn't have the distribution provisioning profile built with my distribution certificate on each device.

My question is, how can I install this distribution provisioning profile on a device that is clicking on the link created for OTA distribution and supposed to run this app? I do know that for Enterprise iOS account, we don't need UDID registration.

Thanks

Comment: You need to plug the device into your mac when you try the install, and see what the true error is in the console.  Plug in your device, open Xcode, go to Organizer.  Find the device and open the Console.  Clear the console, then try to reinstall your app.  Find the error and it will give you some clue as to the real issue.  If it is an enterprise distribution profile, you don't have to register the UDID, and when you package your app, it should embed the enterprise provisioning profile. Post the error from the console and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of potential 'gotchas.' An obvious one, for iOS 7.1 + is that the download html and manifest .plist have to be on an https server. Another is that, even if they are, that server must be correctly handling the MIME type for .ipa files. I think that there's no problem, generally, with Apache servers. Microsoft servers aren't natively set up for this so they have to be 'tuned' by their administrators to see '.ipa' as "application/octet-stream."